# Is there anything in UN charter or laws prohibiting a country to seek the destruction of another country?

Tags: international-law, international-relations, armed-conflict

The question is general, but the obvious context is the fact that Gaza is governed (and presumably, if not for US/Israel support to Fatah, entire Palestinian territory would be governed) by Hamas, whose official goal is destruction of Israel (e.g. see [[1]](http://www.reuters.com/article/2007/03/12/us-palestinians-qaeda-idUSL1229777020070312) and [[2]](http://www.adl.org/anti-semitism/muslim-arab-world/c/hamas-in-their-own-words.html) and [[3]](http://www.palwatch.org/main.aspx?fi=157&doc_id=6024)).

The UN seems strongly in favor of granting Palestine the statehood - and when that happens, it would be a UN member state whose official goal is destruction of Israel.

- **Is there anything in UN charter or laws prohibiting a country to seek a destruction of another country?**
- If there is, what specifically are the measures within UN's power to counteract such a situation? Strongly worded statement? Exclusion from UN? Nothing?

Comment: There is no checklist that one entity needs to fulfill to be called a state. You get to be state when other states recognize you, the same way you get into the UN when the countries already in vote you in. For circumstantial evidence (I haven't actually looked at UN law) why there are no such laws: Iraq and Kuwait were at war with each other and both in the UN. Same for Iraq and Iran. Same for India and Pakistan. Same for Israel and Egypt ... Surely in at least one of those cases, if there were the possibility, one of the parties would have been booted from the UN

Comment: Any real threat to the existence of another state would lead to UNSC involvement whether it comes from another UN member or some terrorist group. Also the state has the right to defend itself under Article 51 of the UN charter. But, of course, a small group of militants is not going to pose a threat to a state with nuclear weapons that has a second strike capability.

Comment: Do you have some reference that agrees that the UN is strongly in favor of granting Palestinian Statehood?  Being willing to consider it is different than supporting it.

Comment: @chad vote counts

Comment: Cite them in your question and I will reverse my vote

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is has no basis in the reality of politics

Comment: Seems to be Israel is much more guilty of "to seek a destructiom of another country" - Palestine - than the other way around...  After all, it's Isreal that's occupied/anexed most of what was supposed to become Palestine...  It's Israel that used terror to scare away tens-of-thousands Palestinians... and it's Israel that kills thousand of Palestinian civilians.

Comment: Hamas is a political party, not a country in itself. But they seem to be accepting a two-state solution and revise their charter (perhaps you can find a draft version somewhere). My guess is that a new charter can not be decided upon until after Israel recognize the right of Palestine and Hamas to exist otherwise I guess there would be some serious trouble arranging the meeting necessary to ratify a new charter.

Comment: @SVilcans - "they seem to be accepting a two-state solution" - that's a big lie. Hell, even FATAH when speaking in lagguages other than English doesn't accept that (witness FATAH ambassador to Iran's speach this week)

Comment: @DVK Gee, got any sources to back up that claim? Perhaps you haven't read any of the articles saying to. http://www.haaretz.com/news/diplomacy-defense/1.587047 http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2011/05/24/136403918/hamas-foreign-minister-we-accept-two-state-solution-with-67-borders http://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/06/world/middleeast/06palestinians.html?_r=0

Comment: @SVilcans - I posted tons of sourses for FATAH stating they want to destoroy Israel on this site previously

Comment: @DVK No, you haven't. Just some anonymous blog posts and looney websites.

Comment: @SVilcans - you mean videos on Youtube of PA representatives speaking what they (and you) don't want to be heard in English and what they really mean when they don't make empty promises to the West? If you have doubts of what they are saying (I don't as I had someone who understands Arabic listen), ask on Skeptics.

Comment: @DVK Exactly! There are organisations like MEMRI that put up a load of videos on YouTube with fake translations so they are not to be trusted. Perhaps you have something in a reliable newspaper?

Comment: @SVilcans - Since the original sounds is available, check yourelf. I did. I am under no obligation to prove to you that the translation is not "fake" when it's a trivial excercise to verify.

Answer (score 7):

The UN charter prohibits using force in disputes. That's all.

You have rigtht to want destruction of another country, not recognize it or dispute its territory, but you are discouraged from applying force.

Those who start wars of aggression, in theory are subject to criminal courts.

Also if a country attacked based on such strive to destruct it, it can legally respond with force.